# QThread::sleep убивает поток в Qt

Tags: c++, qt, многопоточность

Хотел написать простенькое приложение с использоваанием QWaitCondition. Возникла проблема при работе потоков `ActionThread`, а именно при засыпании потока с помощью метода `QThread::sleep(100)` поток ббольше не просыпается и не доходит до строчки `qDebug() << "I slept"`! Если убрать метод `sleep()`, то всё будет работать нормально. Подскажите, в чём загвоздка? Ниже приведён код программы.

Также интересно узнать, кто из потоков владеет QMutex'ом в момент `QWaitCondition::wakeAll()` ? Ведь, по сути Mutex'а им должен владеть лишь один поток. А значит и выполняться будет в каждый момент времени после `QWaitCondition::wakeAll()` лишь один поток. Но в чём же тогда смысл многопоточности? Это пример из документации и мне не очень понятно где тут многопоточность, когда они будут запускаться последовательно... Заранее спасибо за помощь.

main.cpp

```
#include <QApplication>
#include "actionthread.h"
#include "widget.h"

QMutex         qmt;
QWaitCondition condition;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication app(argc, argv);

    ActionThread a_1(1), a_2(2), a_3(3);

    a_1.start();
    a_2.start();
    a_3.start();

    Widget w;
    w.show();

    return app.exec();
}
```

actionthread.h

```
#ifndef ACTIONTHREAD_H
#define ACTIONTHREAD_H
#include <QThread>
#include <QMutex>
#include <QWaitCondition>
#include <QDebug>
#include <QDateTime>

extern QMutex qmt;
extern QWaitCondition condition;

class ActionThread : public QThread
{
    Q_OBJECT
    int id;
public:
    ActionThread(int _id, QObject *parent = 0);
    void run() override;
    void print();
};

#endif // ACTIONTHREAD_H
```

actionthread.cpp

```
#include "actionthread.h"

ActionThread::ActionThread(int _id, QObject *parent) : QThread(parent), id(_id)
{

}

void ActionThread::print(){
    qDebug() << "Current thread has id:" << id << QDateTime::currentDateTime();
    sleep(100);
    qDebug() << "I slept" << id << QDateTime::currentDateTime();
}

void ActionThread::run() {
    forever{
        qmt.lock();
        condition.wait(&qmt);
        print();
        qmt.unlock();
    }
}
```

widget.h

```
#ifndef WIDGET_H
#define WIDGET_H

#include <QWidget>
#include <QDebug>
#include <QKeyEvent>
#include <QTimer>
#include "actionthread.h"

namespace Ui {
class Widget;
}

class Widget : public QWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit Widget(QWidget *parent = nullptr);
    ~Widget();
    void keyPressEvent(QKeyEvent *event);

private:
    Ui::Widget *ui;
};

#endif // WIDGET_H
```

widget.cpp

```
#include "widget.h"
#include "ui_widget.h"

Widget::Widget(QWidget *parent) :
    QWidget(parent),
    ui(new Ui::Widget)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
}

Widget::~Widget()
{
    delete ui;
}

void Widget::keyPressEvent(QKeyEvent *event){
    qDebug() << QChar(event->key());
    condition.wakeAll();
}
```

Comment: Вы ж в курсе, что в функцию ``sleep`` задается время в секундах? ``sleep(100)`` - спать 100 секунд, для задания времени в милисекундах, необходимо использовать ``msleep``.

Comment: Думаю, что просыпается, но через 1 минуту 40 секунд. sleep  принимается количество секунд. Далее, в вашем случае мьютексом после wakeall влвдеть никто не будет, потому что после коллективной спячки будут выведены 2 раза I slept и еще один, если вы нажмете кнопку на клавиатуре

Comment: Спасибо за поправку про секунды, очень глупая ошибка. Но насчёт владения Mutex'ом - в документации написано, что The lockedMutex will be returned to the same locked state. Так что код действительно будет не многопоточный. Для того, чтобы сделать его многопотчным, нужно сразу же после будения потока сделать qmt.unlock();, чтобы никто не владел мьютексом. Потом будет выполняться print(). Так буде происходить во всех 3-х потоках.

Answer (score 2):

а сколь по времени ждали? QTread::sleep(int) это ожидание В СЕКУНДАХ. это первое. Далее, следует учитывать что:

> Avoid using this function if you need to wait for a given condition to
>   change. Instead, connect a slot to the signal that indicates the
>   change or use an event handler (see QObject::event()).

И вообще, постарайтесь избегать QThread:sleep (msleep() и usleep()), поскольку они блокируют эвентлуп.

Еще важно отметить что использование QThread наследованием идея неверная, на что указывает разработчик QT. более подробно предлагаю ознакомиться с этим здесь: https://habr.com/ru/post/150274/

Comment: Спасибо. Насчёт эвентлупа. Я здесь в `run()` решил не писать `exec()`, соответственно не пользуюсь им. Скажите, в чём смысл его использовать, если можно крутиться в `forever {}` макросе, сколько вздумается?

Comment: Поток без запущенного лупа обработки событий не сможет принимать сигналы

Comment: без лупа легче использовать `QRunnable`

Comment: Bearded Beaver главную проблему описал. в случае бесконечного цикла не будут обрабатываться сигналы (кроме блокирующих) и скорее всего события (тут только предположение с 90% уверенности)